# In XSLT, How can I convert 16 year(s), 10 month(s), 4 day(s) into a Years (as an integer/decimal) to show the Service Period for an Employee?

Tags: xslt

In XSLT, How can I convert 16 year(s), 10 month(s), 4 day(s) into a One digit Decimal value as Years to show the Service Period ofan Employee?

Comment: What does the  input look like?

Answer (score 0):

There can be no single correct answer to this question, because different months have different lengths (not to mention that some years are leap years). The expression "16 years, 10 months, 4 days" can represent different lengths, depending on the starting date (which appears to be unknown).

If you are willing to accept an approximation that deems a month to be 1/12 of a year, and a day to be 1/365.2425 of a year, then the calculation can be rather trivial:

```
$years + $months div 12 + $days div 365.2425
```

Comment: Thankyou Michael. I know the decimal/integer will not be an absolute correct length but close to it. I know how this can be achieved mathematically, but I need assistance in XSLT functions to be used on the input "16 years, 10 months, 4 days".  I am rookie to XSLT functionality.

Comment: The above **is** a valid XPath/XSLT expression. You just need to supply the values I used as variables. I don't know how to do that, because you did not show us your input. Please read: [mcve].